# return the answer from "void" to another function

Tags: c++11

I got question how can i return the answer to display because i kept getting an error that void can't return a variable.
   How can i send it to my display function.

```
 void Rational::add(const Rational&h2)
    {

        int num = 0;
        int dem = 0;
        add(h2);
        int P = num * h2.dem + h2.num*dem;
        int Q = dem*h2.dem;


    }

    void display() const; // _p:_q
    {
         if (Q == 1) // e.g. fraction 2/1 will display simply as 2
                cout << P << endl;
            else
                cout <<P << "/" << Q << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

void is the return type of the function you defined, void also means that you're returning nothing. if you had a function "int Rational::add(**)" then you can return a int from the function.

From what I can see you have a few problems:

- You call add() from inside your add() function, this will keep looping until you have a stack overflow
- From what I can see you have a variable Q and P and you want to display them, display isn't a function that belongs to that class so it can't access the variables Q and P which I assume are defined in your header.
- If you do define Q and P inside your header then your function add() isn't writing to them. When you say int Q and int P in your add() function you're defining a new variable with the same name, writing to this local variable isn't going to change the Q and P you may be intending to write to. To solve this you simply don't define Q and P again and just write it without the int.

  P = num * h2.dem + h2.num*dem;

  Q = dem*h2.dem;

Comment: I end up figuring out all of my mistakes and greatly appreciate the help.